# Using SAGA GIS for TPI classification?

Tags: qgis-plugins, saga, tpi

I processed one country with **TPI**, and I got a certain Landforms classification of terrain.
(Topographic Position Index (**TPI**) calculation as proposed by Guisan et al. (1999)).
When I processed only one municipality around that state with **TPI**, I got a different result, in fact more detailed. The calculation parameters were the same. This worries me because I thought to analyze the whole country, and then I would use the zonal statistics tools for each municipality individually and make conclusions based on the obtained forms of the field.
I am writing a scientific paper in this field, so I really care about real data.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the large and small rasters at the same resolution?

Comment: Yes, both are with same cell size 20x20m (DEM)

Comment: I think it is because the classification is mainly based on the SD (standard deviation) of calculated TPI values. Being calculated for the small area, the TPI range is somewhat narrow. So the classification gets relatively sensitive to small change in the TPI value. Rest assured the TPI itself is unchanged.

Comment: I thought that the calculation was based on 8 neighborhood cells.

Comment: You can see changes are displayed on image

Comment: @nagib You are talking about how TPI is calculated. My point is about how the tool put into classes based on TPI. Besides, a lot more than 8 neighboring cells are within 1000m outer radius in this calculation.

Comment: @Kazuhito, You are right. What would you recommend me? Do I analyze for each municipality separately?

Comment: We can try to find sample places to be used as "ground truth". Compare calculated classifications against the real topography (as best as you know about the region). Especially `ridges` (> 1.0 SD) and `valleys` (< -1.0 SD) are good controls (i.e. high and low extremes). If you do not have ridges in your study area, try to expand the area slightly to cover such topography. It will be tedious trial and error but worth trying.

Comment: So when I set the TPI for the continent then I would get different information again. I might ask a question on the SAGA GIS forum. Thank you very much.

Comment: I found out what the problem was.
I have square DEM. The state has curved boundaries. All pixels across the boundary have a value of 0 (was clipped). The TPI algorithm counted these pixels as well, and so I got such a result. I clipped again my country  and removed pixels with a value of 0 and got a satisfactory result. ;-)

Comment: I think you should write an answer based on your comment.  Self-answering is both permitted and encouraged,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I have square DEM. The state has curved boundaries. All pixels across the boundary have a value of 0 (was clipped). The TPI algorithm counted these pixels as well, and so I got such a result. I clipped again my country and removed pixels with a value of 0 and got a satisfactory result.